# Tcl: strange behavior of string list

Tags: string, list, tcl

In my following code, I generate a string list in a `for` loop like this:

```
set section 5;
set value 2;
set value_range_new "";
for { set i [expr -$section-1]} {$i <= $section} {incr i} {
  if {$i < [expr -$section]} {
    lappend value_range_new "\<[expr [expr $i+1]*$value]";  
  } elseif {$i == $section} {
    lappend value_range_new "\>[expr $i*$value]";
  } else {
    lappend value_range_new "\[[expr $i*$value]\,[expr [expr $i +1]*$value]\)";
  }
}
```

then if I `puts` the list out, the result is following:

```
<-10 {[-10,-8)} {[-8,-6)} {[-6,-4)} {[-4,-2)} {[-2,0)} {[0,2)} {[2,4)} {[4,6)} {[6,8)} {[8,10)} >10
```

The confusing point is I do not understand where the `{}` comes from. If I define the list manually like following :

```
set a "\<-8 \[-8,-6\) \[-6,-4\) ";
```

the puts result has no `{}`. So what's wrong with my code, and how to remove/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tcl, you need to be aware which commands want to work with lists and which commands want to work with strings. `lappend` is a list command. `puts` takes a string. When you give `puts` a list, Tcl will convert the list into its string representation. That means that you'll see some extra braces and perhaps backslashes to protect list elements that have special characters (like `[` and `]`).

You can convert the list into a string easily with the `join` command.

For building strings, the `format` command can aid readability.

Additionally, you don't need to next `expr` commands, use parentheses; and [brace your expressions](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10225):

```
set section 5;
set value 2;
set value_range_new "";
for { set i [expr {-$section-1}]} {$i <= $section} {incr i} {
  set this [expr {$i * $value}]
  set next [expr {($i + 1) * $value}]
  if {$i < -$section} {
    lappend value_range_new [format {<%d} $next]  
  } elseif {$i == $section} {
    lappend value_range_new [format {>%d} $this]
  } else {
    lappend value_range_new [format {[%d,%d)} $this $next]
  }
}
puts [join $value_range_new]
```

outputs

```
<-10 [-10,-8) [-8,-6) [-6,-4) [-4,-2) [-2,0) [0,2) [2,4) [4,6) [6,8) [8,10) >10
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. `join` works well for my case. And the method of `$this` and `$next` is very helpful, too.

Comment: Can't normally format the code in comments, so add the answer with shorter variant of algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The shorter variant of algorithm. Not a single `if` is needed actually.

```
set section 5;
set value 2;
set this [expr {-$section * $value}]
set value_range_new [format {<%d} $this]  
for {set i -$section} {$i < $section} {incr i} {
  lappend value_range_new [format {[%d,%d)} $this [incr this $value]]
}
lappend value_range_new [format {>%d} $this]

puts [join $value_range_new]
```